# How to feed fish when you're ill?

Tags: fish, feeding, betta

I recently came down with a cold; I currently normally feed my fish by hand twice a day (morning and afternoon). However, I was wondering if the fact that I'm sick creates a problem for this.

Also, I do wash my hands quite regularly, but I did realize that the last time I fed them it had been around an hour since I had done so.

I currently live alone, so I can't ask another family member to do it for me.

I tested negative for coronavirus after I started feeling ill if that's relevant. **Edit:** A subsequent test was positive, so the original test was evidently incorrect.

Comment: fish will not be infected by human pathogens as far as i know.

Comment: Why not use a spoon?

Comment: Are you concerned about infecting the fish, or about not being able to feed them propperly?

Comment: @Berend Good idea.

Comment: @Allerleirauh Infecting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are worried (and I simply can’t answer whether your sniffles would be contagious), don’t use your bare hands, if only for your own peace of mind. Personally I’d think washing your hands should be enough and unless you are sneezing into the water, being near the aquarium is also harmless.

But of course the human psyche is a peculiar thing and sometimes avoiding a situation is the best approach:

So if you don’t want to handle the food, flakes can be distributed with a spoon, small spatula or tip of a knife, larger chunks picked up with tweezers or chopsticks.

The same solution of course works for larger pets as well - skip the hand feeding, use utensils.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I use a spoon and it helps to feed them at the same times each day so you don't forget. Also setting an alarm on your phone helps.